# TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. Reactive-Forms Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

Hi i have tried to do reactive form validation in angular 11 but its showing following error in terminal.

error **TS2531 object is possibly null.**

my code in register-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-form',
  templateUrl: './register-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register-form.component.css']
})
  
export class RegisterFormComponent  {
       title = 'Register Form';
        angForm: FormGroup;
        submitted = false;
        
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.angForm = this.fb.group({
        title: ['', Validators.required ],
        name: ['', Validators.required ],
        gender: ['', Validators.required],
        address: ['', Validators.required ],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
    } 
}
```

in register-form.component.html

```
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors['required']">
                  Name is required.
                </div>
            </div>
```

when i run its showing error in

register-form.component.html:26:17 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Your template should contain a reference to the FormGroup defined in the "register-form.component.ts" :  <form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-group "> -- The rest of your template -- </form>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

your html can look like this,

```
<div class="form-group " [formGroup]="angFormInstance">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text">
</div>
<div *ngIf="angFormInstance.controls['name'].invalid && (angFormInstance.controls['name'].dirty || angFormInstance.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="angFormInstance.controls['name'].errors['required']">
        Name is required.
    </div>
</div>
```

and ts file be like,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-form',
  templateUrl: './register-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register-form.component.css']
})
  
export class RegisterFormComponent  {
       title = 'Register Form';
        angForm: FormGroup;
        submitted = false;

        get angFormInstance(): any {
          return this.angForm
        }
        
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.angForm = fb.group({
        title: ['', Validators.required ],
        name: ['', Validators.required ],
        gender: ['', Validators.required],
        address: ['', Validators.required ],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register-form',
    templateUrl: './register-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register-form.component.css']
})
export class RegisterFormComponent  {
    title = 'Register Form';
    angForm: FormGroup;
    submitted = false;
        
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.angForm = this.fb.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required ],
            name: ['', Validators.required ],
            gender: ['', Validators.required],
            address: ['', Validators.required ],
            email: ['', Validators.required],
            acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
    } 

    get angFormInstance():any {
        return this.angForm.controls;
    }
}
```

HTML File:

```html
<div class="form-group " [formGroup]="angFormInstance">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text">

    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="(angFormInstance.name.touched || 
    submitted) && angFormInstance.name.errors?.required">
        Name is required
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.